# Google Polymer Navigation

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-starter-kit

The navigation of the official Polymer Project website is really incredible, the best I have ever seen: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/start/

I've been trying to implement it myself, and I know the code is open source, but I can't get it to work.. I'd like to have a similar layout for a static website (meaning no python), and I was hoping someone might be able to help out.. the code is here: https://github.com/Polymer/docs/blob/master/app/1.0/index.html, but when I try to integrate it myself then I just get a blank page..

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I think maybe you should be more specific. Are there any errors in console, 404 status codes for dependencies? If possible, maybe create a code sample with your attempt on GitHub and post link here?

Comment: @TomaszPluskiewicz I tried to put the code into codepen, but don't think codepen can import components..  
  
Running the code locally (using the polymer starter kit) will show the white navigation bar, but the search icon is missing, and the search bar is located on the righthand side instead of being hidden: http://i.imgur.com/PstcS8B.png ..  
  
http://codepen.io/blsbdflskjfskldfj/pen/NRPgdV?editors=1000